# Reading a csv file into an array

Tags: php, database, arrays

I'm incredibly new to php so please bear with me and help me learn. I have a .csv file that's 33 lines long (including titles) and 4 columns wide. I want to read that data into an array so I can begin to sort and manipulate it.

What is the best course of action for doing so? Code snippits are the best way for me to learn code as I can read, interpret, use and then spit back questions I may have.

Comment: one of [many](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=array+csv+php) possible duplicates of [How to create an array from a CSV file using PHP and the fgetcsv function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using fgetcsv returns an array from a csv file line.  To see it exploded you run put your returned array into a print_r() function.  To see that in a pretty-print type view you can wrap it in `<pre>` tags

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<pre>".print_r($data)." <br /></pre>";
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

That should be a good start.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: That's pretty much how I do it. +1