# fgetcsv() not respecting newlines while converting .csv file to array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I have this array with airport codes and city names (around 3500 lines).

```
code,city
"Abilene, TX ",ABI
"Adak Island, AK ",ADK
"Akiachak, AK ",KKI
"Akiak, AK ",AKI
"Akron/Canton, OH ",CAK
"Akuton, AK ",KQA
"Alakanuk, AK ",AUK
"Alamogordo, NM ",ALM
```

I need to convert that file into a php array. This is my code so far:

```
if(($handle = fopen('test.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Although I'm setting the delimiter and enclousure characters for the fgetcsv function, im getting this as a result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => code
    [1] => city
"Abilene
    [2] => TX "
    [3] => ABI
"Adak Island
    [4] => AK "
    [5] => ADK
"Akiachak
    [6] => AK "
    [7] => KKI
"Akiak
    [8] => AK "
    [9] => AKI
"Akron/Canton
    [10] => OH "
    [11] => CAK
"Akuton
    [12] => AK "
    [13] => KQA
"Alakanuk
    [14] => AK "
    [15] => AUK
"Alamogordo
    [16] => NM "
    [17] => ALM
)
```

Comment: Are you sure those are `"` chars and not the fancy 66's and 99's that MS loves to sprinkle everywhere?

Comment: Works fine for me. Probably a bug in your `PHP_VERSION`. (Which is it?) Alternatively try `var_dump(array_map("str_getcsv", file($fn)))`.

Comment: @StefanPantke: Now that you mention it. He gets exactly one record out of it. So it's the line breaks which are not recognized, therefore the quotes being misinterpreted as well.

Comment: See also php.ini setting `auto_detect_line_endings`

Comment: @StefanPantke: The `1` is just the result of `print_r()` which gets written out by the `echo` *after* print_r itself already threw its output out. (Why it's also not within the pre tags.)

Comment: @MarcB yes, the " are normal quotes

Comment: @StefanPantke i fixed the output, still that is not the issue. I think Mario kind of has a point with the line breaks though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an array from a CSV file using PHP and the fgetcsv function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If it's the linebreaks, you can try the brute-force method with:

```
$file = file_get_contents("test.csv");
$data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file));
print_r($data);
```

[`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) is available with PHP 5.3, or as workaround in the manual, via [upgradephp](http://www.google.com/search?q=upgradephp) or [PHP_Compat](http://www.google.com/search?q=PHP_Compat).

Comment: Let's demonstrate `/\R+/` or `/\v+/` here.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);/// (PHP's detection of line endings) write at the top.


$csvrows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filepath));
$csvheader = array_shift($csvrows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($csvrows as $row) {
   $csv[] = array_combine($csvheader, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try-

```
$csv = array();

if (($file = fopen('test.csv', 'r')) === false) {
    throw new Exception('There was an error loading the CSV file.');
} else {  
   while (($line = fgetcsv($file, 1000)) !== false) {
      $csv[] = $line;
   }
   fclose($handle);
}
```