# PHP Explode Multiple Lines

Tags: php, csv, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create an array from a CSV file using PHP and the fgetcsv function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function)

I have a file that contains multiple rows of comma delimited values.  A sample of the file is:

> 1359739665,511251515,115151515,start,1277771750,,2215812581258,31.55.115.12,0,0
>   1359739665,511251515,115151515,restore,1277771750,,2215812581258,31.55.115.12,0,0
>   1359739665,511251515,115151515,restore,1277771750,,2215812581258,31.55.115.12,0,0
>   1359739665,511251515,115151515,end,1277771750,,2215812581258,31.55.115.12,0,0

I basically need to iterate through each row.  At the moment, this is my code:

```
$file = "log.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$fields = explode(',', $contents);

foreach ($fields as $row)
    {
       echo $row;
    }
```

This works fine for outputting the entire file.  But my question is how do I iterate one row at a time.  Each row essentially ends without the comma but I'm not sure how to force a break there.  What I'd like to do is this (even though code is incorrect):

```
foreach ($fields as $row)  //need $row to equal each row of the log
  {
      echo $row[0];  // will output 1359739665
      echo $row[1];  // will output 511251515
      etc...
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: don't, use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use either [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) or [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) to read CSV data.

**An example using [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv):**

```
if (($handle = fopen("log.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo $row[0] . "\n"; // Will output  data contained in the first column
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

**An example using [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv):**

```
$file = "log.txt";
$contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$csvRows = array_map('str_getcsv', $contents);

foreach($csvRows as $row) {
    echo $row[0] . "\n"; // Will output  data contained in the first column
}
```

Using `explode()` to manually parse CSV data might cause problems when your CSV fields may contain commas within their values or when the file endings of the CSV file isn't consistent. **It is best to use the specialized functions described above as they are tailored for this specific task.**

Comment: Thanks Andrew - that worked perfectly.  Any preference to fgetcsv vs. str_getcsv?  My files will always be identical in terms of the number of columns, etc.

Comment: [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) is better for large data-sets as your file isn't loaded all at once into memory. For small to medium-size data-sets, [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) is usually easier to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `file_get_contents` just use [`file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

```
$array_of_contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Once you've done that you can iterate over the array and get each individual "column" of the file with `str_getcsv`:

```
foreach (file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $line) {
    foreach (str_getcsv($file) as $fields) {
        echo $fields[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count lines of .txt file, get one row at a time with foreach(), explode the row

Answer (score 0):

Explode by new line

```
$fields = explode("\n", $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach(file('my.csv') as $line) {
    $record = str_getcsv($line, ',');
    var_dump($record);
}
```

The function [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) returns an array with every single line of a file. It's very nice for iterating over the lines of a file. Then inside the foreach loop you can explode each line to single record.

Thanks to Andrew Moore I would advice you to use the function `str_getcsv()` instead of `explode()`