# Using PHP to search CSV by Column?

Tags: php, html, csv

Having trouble searching CSV file by Column. For example, I have the following CSV file:

> NAME, HAS AN IPHONE, HAS ANDROID
>
> bob,          yes,           no,
>
> fred,         no,            yes,

How could I search column 2 for a 'yes' value using php,
then return only the rows with "yes" in second column results?

Comment: Depends on your code to read the CSV.

Comment: i dont knwo what you mean AbraCadaver ?? $file = fopen("example.csv","r");
$fileholder = fgetcsv($file);

Comment: You need to print out "yes" and "no" or count them? What's the purpose for it?

Comment: well for example i would just want to print all the users who have yes in there second column. Not displaying those with a no in the second column.

Comment: How is it possible that you are even asking this question?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have already [parsed the csv file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1269562/3110638).
The second parameter of [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function is *mixed* `$search_value`

> If specified, then only keys containing these values are returned.

To search a specific column, use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$res = array_keys(array_column($csv, 1), "yes");
```

See [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/414266); This would return keys of of all "yes" matches in the second column.

Answer (score 5):

I think, This can help you. Read about [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

```
 <?php

    $result  = [];
    if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
          if($data[1] == 'yes') //Checks second column is 'yes' 
              array_push($result, $data);
        }
        fclose($handle);

      var_dump($result);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It should be array_push($result, $data);

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried anything if so please post that also, you may find this helpful

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));

foreach($csv as $line){
    if($line[1] == 'yes'){
        //do what ever you want
        echo "found yes";
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i don't want to search rows ( lines ) instead only columns though ?

Comment: you may find this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191682/how-to-read-specific-columns-of-a-csv-file-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what i tried and it worked for searching for a value in rows.
Then you can get the values of the rows and use it.

```
<?php

$file = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$str = "n@gmail.com";
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== false)
{
    if(in_array($str, $data))
    {
        foreach ($data as $i)
        {
            echo $i."<br>";
        }   
    }
}
fclose($file);
?>
```