# Adding CbuttonColumn to Csv Header Column array (Used in CgridView) - Yii Framework

Tags: yii

I am trying to add Delete button to CgridView , I am displaying CgridView columns from CSV file headers . I am storing Csv columns names in array, Now i want to add one more button column to delete the record.

Here is my code,

```
<?php 
$file = fopen('D:/xampp/htdocs/ccvv7/images/importcsv/load.csv', 'r');
$data = array();
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

    $data[] = $line;
}
fclose($file);
$columns = array();

foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
    $columns[] = array(
        'name' => $key,
        'header' => $value,
    );
}
$data = array_slice($data, 1);
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($data, array(
    'keyField' => 0,
));?>

<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' =>'BCImported-grid',
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => $columns,
    )); ?>
```

Please look into the code, now i need to add one more button column to `$columns` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to $column :

```
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{delete}',
            'deleteButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("delete",array("id"=>$data["id"]))',
        ),
```

Comment: but then this doesn't necessarily delete the row in the CSV file. still need to implement the logic in the delete action.