# How to pass data from a CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I know this is going to be super simple when someone shows me but I can't seem to work it out. I'm trying to read in a csv file like the below and then pass it to a function called 'row'. The CSV has 4 columns, I want to read in a row and then split the data on a ',' and put it into the line `$this->Row(array('','','',''));` where I then want to move onto the next line, until I've finished all lines, does anyone have any ideas?

1,1,1,1

2,2,2,2

3,3,3,3

```
function LoadData($file)
{
    $lines = file($file);
    $data = array();   
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $data[] = explode(',',trim($line));
        $this->Row(array('','','',''));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function?rq=1

Comment: please use manual: http://pl1.php.net/fgetcsv

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

    function getCsv($file) {
        if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

            while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 100, ',' ) ) !== FALSE ) {
                $this->Row($data);
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }

    getCsv('/path/to/file.csv');

?>
```