# PHP - Search for an URL patterns in a CSV file and replace it

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have a csv file with multiple columns, in some of these columns there are some  HTML tags that looks like `StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=6348`. Then there is a folder that contains all images renamed with ID.Extension i.e. 6348.jpg.

I would like to create a script that searches for `StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=6348` and replaces it with `http://newdomain.com/images/6348.jpg`.

Note that not all the files are .jpg so the extension needs to be checked when the file is found.

```
$file = fopen("images.csv", "r");

$lines = array();

while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
//$line is an array of the csv elements
$lines[] = $line;
}
foreach ($lines as $line => $data) {
$data = preg_replace_callback('/StreamHandler\.ashx\?SubscriptionID=([0-9]+)/', function($matches) {
   $img = $matches[1]; //get the filename
   $img = glob("/Users/sandro/Sites/test/destination/" . $img . ".*"); //find the file in the fileserver (in the current directory)
   $img[0] = str_replace ( "/Users/sandro/Sites/test/destination/", 'http://newdomain.com/images/', $img[0] );

   if( isset($img[0]) ) { //was there a match?
      return $img[0]; //replace
   }

   return $matches[0]; //dont replace because file doesnt exist
}, $data);

print_r($data);
}

fclose($file);
```

I've written the part to open and read the csv file but the search is still missing. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code you have written? Its best to show that you have made an attempt before posting here.

Comment: I've added the code I've already written

Comment: Are these string prefixes constant? For example, `StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=`?

Comment: `preg_match` or `parse_str` \ `parse_url` for finding a pattern. `fwrite`, `file_put_contents` for writing to a file

Comment: StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID= is always the same what changes is just the ID afterwards

Comment: I should have figured out how to search but now it's not looping the file

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to find the string you want to search, then look the file extension up, and replace.

- Find matches to replace
- See if the file exists by looking for the filename
- If it exists, replace string
- If it doesn't exist, keep current string

```
$csv = preg_replace_callback('/StreamHandler\.ashx\?SubscriptionID=([0-9]+)/', function($matches) {
   $file = $matches[1]; //get the filename
   $file = glob($file .".*"); //find the file in the fileserver (in the current directory)

   if( isset($file[0]) ) { //was there a match?
      return 'http://newdomain.com/images/'. $file[0]; //replace
   }

   return $matches[0]; //dont replace because file doesnt exist
}, $csv);
```

Example

- I have the file `6348.png`.
- My `csv` file holds: `StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=6348,StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=6349,StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=635,StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=64`

The output:

```
http://newdomain.com/images/6348.png,StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=6349,StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=635,StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=64
```

Comment: The output should be only http://newdomain.com/images/6348.png. Will this script replace only /StreamHandler\.ashx\?SubscriptionID=3232 with the new url in the csv file?

Comment: Yes, it will only find a string like `StreamHandler.ashx?SubscriptionID=6349` and replace just that string with the new string `http://newdomain.com/images/6349.png`

Comment: Ok and how do I make it loop through all the csv file rows?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function

Comment: So I managed to loop through the whole document but now it needs to save the new values to the csv file, any help here?

Comment: Just overwrite the file with `file_put_contents()`.