# Function to open the CSV and output the contents as an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I've got a CSV file containing 4  fields - ID, Product Group Name, Price & Items.

The  Items  field  is  a  list  of  products  (more  than  one)  that  belong  to  the  group, separated by a `|` symbol.

**For example:**  `7, Fruit Basket, 9.99, Apple|Banana|Pear`

Could you please help me to write a function to open the CSV file and output the contents as an array with the items nested at the second level.

The ID of the Product Group should be used for the key of the array.

Comment: Have you tried the function explode in combination with a foreach to handle all the data?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1269615/4248328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$result = array();
$file = fopen('data.csv', "r");
while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
    $id = array_shift($row);
    $row[2] = str_getcsv($row[2], "|");
    $result[$id] = $row;
}
print_r($result);
```

data.csv file:

```
7, Fruit Basket, 9.99, Apple|Banana|Pear
8, Fruit Basket, 9.99, Apple|Banana|Pear
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Fruit Basket
            [1] =>  9.99
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  Apple
                    [1] => Banana
                    [2] => Pear
                )
        )
    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Fruit Basket
            [1] =>  9.99
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  Apple
                    [1] => Banana
                    [2] => Pear
                )
        )
)
```

Heads up: My code works for this data structure only. If the nested items on an other position in the data, it does not work!