# Convert CSV into Array

Tags: php

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Did,status
"123","Active"
"456","Not-Active"
"789","Active"
....and so on
```

I would like to be able to convert it into an array that looks like this:

```
$DidStatus = array("123"=>"Active", "456"=>"Not-Active", "789"=>"Active");
```

**I tried this but it's not what I'm looking for:**

```
$file = file_get_contents("test.csv");
$data = array_map("str_getcsv", preg_split('/\r*\n+|\r+/', $file));
print_r($data);
```

but the output is not the one I'm looking for:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Did
            [1] => status
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => Active
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 456
            [1] => Not-Active
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 789
            [1] => Active
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an array from a CSV file using PHP and the fgetcsv function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function)

Comment: Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: have you even tried using google? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269562/how-to-create-an-array-from-a-csv-file-using-php-and-the-fgetcsv-function

Comment: @MagnusEriksson See edited code. I added what I tried. Thanks

Comment: You don't have the most efficient logic to read as a csv; but take the next step and use `$data = array_column($data, 1, 0);`

Comment: Using `file()` would be better than `file_get_content()` and that `preg_split()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `fgetcsv()`

```
<?php

    $handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
    $result = Array();
    fgetcsv($handle); //Removes the first line of headings in the csv
    while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        $result[$data[0]] = $data[1];
    }
    print_r($result); //the result
?>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways to do it, but given your current code, just extract an array of the `1` values and index it by the `0` values.

```
unset($data[0]); //If needed to remove the header row

$data = array_column($data, 1, 0);
```

You may consider this as an alternate for the first step (not sure if `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` is absolutely necessary):

```
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). That is meant to be used for something like this.

```
$arr = array();
$file = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
while (($result = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
{
    $arr[] = $result;
}
fclose($file);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this package [league/csv](https://packagist.org/packages/league/csv) and you can find instructions on how to use it [here](http://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/) - one of the first examples shows how to convert csv to array