# Convert CSV string row with no delimiters into an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

So I'm attempting to explode my string of csv rows into an array and I'm having a difficult time.

Let me lead you through the steps:

`var_dump($line);` returns an string as this: `:string 'TEST        Test        Test2           Test3`

Now, when I have an `.txt` file, and I call `$arr = explode("\t", $line);`, the `$arr` returns an array

> ```
> array (size=15)  
>   0 => string 'TEST      ' (length=11)  
>   1 => string 'Test' (length=4)  
>   2 => string 'Test 2' (length=0)  
>   3 => string 'Test 3' (length=6)
> ```

But if I have an `.csv` file, and I attempt to explode it, I get left with an array string as such:

`array (size=1)
  0 => string 'TEST     Test      Test2  Test3'`

I tried doing the following but I'm not having much luck: `$test = str_getcsv($line, "\t", '', '');` - All the examples for `str_getcsv` show it like this:

```
$str = "the,cat,in,the,hat";
$arr = str_getcsv($str);
print_r($arr);
```

But mine aren't comma separated, but instead all tabbed.

All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1269615/2877427 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a file to get the csv's you should be able to use `fgetcsv` for this [read more here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

```
$filename = "";
if (($handle = fopen($filename, "r")) !== false) {
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, "\t")) !== false) {
        // $data should be an array of all the items in here.
        print_r($line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies for the late follow-up, but this worked great @The Blacksmith! Would you be able to upvote my answer if it made sense :)